# Does SSDT bulid script for only changed objects?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-data-tools

I'm currently in the process of redesigning our department's source control strategy using Team Foundation Server (TFS) in regard to database objects. Essentially, we store nothing in TFS at this time. I have discovered SSDT and really enjoy their integration within Visual Studio and think it will make our transition into TFS much easier.

So, Does SSDT have the capability of generating scripts based on the delta's of my SSDT project verses what is in our server? It seems from what I have researched, I will only be able to generate an entire database script.

Requirements (Mind you, our developers do not have ddl access to production):

1. I cannot drop a database to re-create it
2. I cannot drop ALL objects like all stored procs to re-create them but only what I need
3. Tables will need to be altered not dropped and only what has changed
4. Dacpac's are out of the question
5. Our best option based on our environment at this time is to use scripts for updates

Our database environment is currently SQL Server 2008 R2. My SSDT version is the latest 2013 that was published in June.

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you found any solution toget the delta sql?

Comment: I think Peter Schott's answer below is as close as I could get. We ended up having to ditch SSDT before I could find out if Peter's response would help us because we had circular references with linked servers from one SQL Database back to another. SSDT errored with these every time because it wanted to build those objects and it didn't work. I could not find a way around that. Unfortunately we did not have rights to change this in the database. Sorry I cannot be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you do a publish from the project you will pretty much meet all of these requirements, though dacpacs are built as part of the process. The schema compare and pre/post deploy scripts are stored in the dacpac and the publish reads what "should" be present against what is currently in the database. It then generates a change script of all necessary changes to bring the database in line with the project.

Make sure you use the Refactor/Rename when renaming objects - that will cut down on the table drop/recreate operations. You may want to be careful with the "Drop objects not in the project" options. If you haven't been careful with making sure all objects created in your production server are in your project, you could accidentally drop something important just because someone didn't get it checked in.

There are command lines to the SQLPackage command that can generate change detail reports and scripts that you can use. The scripts need to be run through SQLCMD or in SQLCMD mode, but you can definitely produce scripts pretty easily.